# Why did V need the police chief?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

In the film *V for Vendetta*, the following conversation takes place:

> Finch: Rookwood. Why didn't you come forward before? What were you waiting for?
>
> V: For you, Inspector. I needed you.

I have tried to come up with a reason why V needed him, and have concluded that V didn't need him. Rather the author needed him (the police chief) to provide another perspective on the plot: a plot device.

Is that reasonable?

Comment: They altered the characters somewhat in the movie.  Finch in the comics was a dogged and old-style investigator, and while he was a plot device to reveal V's backstory, he was also the last good man stuck in the government, and V used Finch to kill himself once V's plan could no longer be stopped.  V saw no place for himself in the new world, so (in his mind?) he did need someone like Finch to remove him and let Evey take his place.  The movie made it into a dramatic last stand thing that I didn't really comprehend.

Comment: I always assumed that he needed an honest man running the police or the chairman wouldn't have made himself vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

V talked of liberating people by giving them the truth. What better way or what more symbolic way to do that than to help the police inspector find the truth? And also, I think V hoped that the police inspector would be inspired to make the world a more just place if he knew the whole truth. V knew the world would go on once he died and someone needed to take his place in ensuring justice is served. That would be Evey with the help of the police inspector.

Answer (score 2):

V needed the police chief (Finch) to persuade Creedy to kill Sutler.

First V makes Finch put Creedy under surveillance.

> V (pretending to be Rookwood): But if you want that recording, you'll do what I tell you to do.
> Put Creedy under 24-hour surveillance. When I feel safe he can't pick
> his nose without you knowing, I'll contact you again.

Then he convinces Creedy that he's under surveillance because Sutler doesn't trust him anymore and is planning to remove him.

> V: Sutler can no longer trust you, can he, Mr. Creedy? And we both
> know why. After I destroy Parliament, his only chance will be to offer
> them someone else, some other piece of meat.
>
> Creedy: And who will that be?
>
> V: You, Mr. Creedy. A man as smart as you has probably considered
> this. A man as smart as you probably has a plan. That plan is the
> reason Sutler no longer trusts you. It's the reason why you're being
> watched right now, why there are eyes and ears in every room of this
> house and a tap on every phone.
>
> Creedy: Bollocks.
>
> V: Oh, a man as smart as you, I think, knows otherwise.
>
> Creedy: What do you want?
>
> V: Sutler. Come, now, Mr. Creedy, you knew this was coming. You knew
> that one day it'd be you or him. That's why Sutler's been kept
> underground for security purposes. That's why there are several of
> your men close to Sutler, men that can be counted on. All you have to
> do is say the word.